# Raise an event notification to a specific client when a user is registered/created on Identity Server

Tags: identityserver4

I am creating an AdminUI for my users where I set all the permission. As part of the requirements, every time that a user logins on my IdentityServer I need to set some default permissions, but those are handle on my Admin application. Which is the best way to raise an event to let that application that a user was created on the IdentityServer?

Comment: What are the communication options between your IdentityServer and AdminApp? One or two separate applications? Perhaps your Admin app just can poll/query the database every X seconds and see if there are any new records since last check?

Comment: two separate applications, but my admin app doesn't have access to identity database

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is i think to create a simple WebApi in IdentityServer that returns the latest users and then let the other application poll this API every X seconds. In that way the system is cleanly decoupled. Perhaps expose the data as a a RSS XML document or a JSON list of items.

There is a built in [eventing model](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/events.html) in IdentityServer that you could use and push notifications to the Admin application. But push is a bit more complicated to get right, especially how to deal with all the failre/error cases.

Answer (score 0):

I's suggest to add a [custom event sink](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/events.html#custom-sinks) to process [UserLoginSuccessEvent](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/main/src/IdentityServer4/src/Events/UserLoginSuccessEvent.cs) or any other event you need, here is list of all builtin events. Find their code [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/main/src/IdentityServer4/src/Events).
In the custom sink as suggested in the other answer you can call an API on admin app to inform it about changes.

[Here](https://github.com/KarateJB/AspNetCore.IdentityServer4.Sample/blob/poc-eventsink/AspNetCore.IdentityServer4/AspNetCore.IdentityServer4.Auth/Events/UserProfileCacheSink.cs) is a sample for custom sink.

Answer (score 0):

I think to keep two applications decoupled you better to setup a service-bus for simple implementation a sub/pub mechanism. when any user complete registration(or any other actions),then as mentioned in another answer handle the events and add message. admin UI should subscribed before to receive these messages with some information to create a user related data.